# Multiple DispatcherServlets same spring back end

Tags: spring, model-view-controller

Im planning on running multiple sites all using the same spring mvc application as the controller/service/dao layer. I think the way i will try to do it is to set up 2 DispatcherServlets mapped to different paths in web.xml, then i can put the different configurations for each version of the site in site1-servlet.xml and site2-servlet.xml.

After a bit of playing around ive got it up and serving pages, the immediate problem is that each controller method has to be mapped to /site1 and /site2. I dont want to have to hard code these into the controllers as there may be may more versions of the site soon.

First question is am i doing this the right way to begin with?

Secondly, what is the best way to get the requests to map to different DispatcherServlets, hopefully based on the Host: they arrive on, much like a VirtualHost in apache?

Cheers!
NFV

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are on the right track.  One thing you could do to help you with the requestmapping is to use the

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping"></bean>
```

That way all you need is to annotate the method with @RequestMapping instead of using a path.

URL would end up being something like

```
  http://mylocalhost:8080/site1/mycontroller/myMethod
```